# No instances in ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I’m having a little weekend play with Terraform and AWS but have hit a brick wall with ECS… I *think* my config is right, but for some reason the EC2 instance that my task definition spawns is not binding to my cluster. My definition resource looks like this:

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "myapp" {
  name                        = "myapp-launchcfg"
    image_id                    = "ami-0acc9f8be17a41897"
    instance_type               = "t2.micro"
    associate_public_ip_address = true
    iam_instance_profile        = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.myapp.arn}"
    key_name                    = "${aws_key_pair.myapp.key_name}"

    user_data = "#!/bin/bash\necho ECS_CLUSTER=${aws_ecs_cluster.myapp.name} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config"
}
```

Everything is created properly, no errors, but there are no instances running in the ECS cluster… yet there is an EC2 instance running. I’m not sure if the `user_data` block is right, or being executed as when I grab a screenshot of the terminal from the EC2 instance it’s sat there at a login prompt. Any ideas?

Comment: Has it joined the default ECS cluster?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I've removed the default ECS cluster, I wanted to start with a completely blank slate.

Comment: Can you check the ecs logs in the EC2 instance.

Comment: Are you doing this from a Windows machine by any chance? Regardless, the only definitive way to troubleshoot this is to check the userdata logs on the machine.

Comment: Task definition has no relationship with cluster. You have to pass cluster name while executing the service or task. please post your task or service code.

Comment: Also, please post sone content snippet of /var/log/cloud-init-output.log

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed. Was useful to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the comments so far, I managed to resolve this in the end so I'll put the solution here for anyone else to stumble across.

The main issue was that I was creating a VPC and a Subnet, but when I looked further AWS was also creating a default subnet, and because I'd made a custom one and bound to that the default wasn't getting used. Upon further inspection of the binding between the EC2 instance and subnet, the binding was for the default subnet, so in the end I had to change my initial subnet resource within Terraform from `resource "aws_subnet" {}` to `resource "aws_default_subnet" {}` to provide the settings I wanted to this default instance.

Second, and finally, I had to modify my routing table to route all traffic from `0.0.0.0/0` to my Internet Gateway.

Up and running now, still have a lot to learn but there you go!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a load balancer in conjunction with your ECS cluster and your autoscaling group. To bind an autoscaling group to an ECS cluster this way, you can provision an `aws_autoscaling_attachment`. This will make sure any instance launched by that auto scaling group is registered with the target group (in case of an Application Load Balancer), or directly to the ELB if that's what your using. Example:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_attachment" "default" {
    autoscaling_group_name = "${var.my_asg_name}"
    alb_target_group_arn = "${var.my_alb_target_group_arn}"
    #elb = "${var.my_elb_id}" #in case of elb
}
```

In this case, you can use ECS optimized AMI's, which have the ECS agent preinstalled and configured. For e.g. linux you'd then have to provide an env var using your user data script, such as:

`echo 'ECS_CLUSTER=my_cluster_name' >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config`

This will link the agent to the correct cluster, for deployment.